# how to get count for each email sent

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am written a code for sending email by multiple sender(created in list) to one recipient. I can iterate that list multiple time. Now i want to show count for each emailID in list for eg. abc1@d.com count=2, abc2@d.com count=3.

I am a bigenner. Please suggest a way to do it.
below is my code to send eamil.

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("toAddress"));
        List<File> uploadedFiles= saveUploadedFiles(request);
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("email"));
        System.out.println("Reached servlet");
        response.getWriter().print("Hello"+request.getParameter("email"));

        System.out.println("hii"+request.getParts());
        //List<File> uploadedFiles= saveUploadedFiles(request);
        String toAddress=request.getParameter("toAddress");
        String subject=request.getParameter("subject");
        String content=request.getParameter("content");
        int sleeptime=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("emailInterval"));
        int noOfEmailToSend=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("noOfEmailToSend"));
        int iterationInterval=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("iterationInterval"));
        String resultMessage = ""; //null

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        List<String> list = (List<String>) session.getAttribute("name"); 


        System.out.println(list);


        List<String> sub=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=1;i<=noOfEmailToSend;i++)
        {
             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
                sb.append(subject).append(i);
                sub.add(sb.toString());
        }           
        try {   
                for(int j=0;j<noOfEmailToSend;j++)
                {       
                    Iterator<String> sendersInputIterate = list.iterator();
                    Iterator<String> subject1 = sub.iterator();
                    while (sendersInputIterate.hasNext() && subject1.hasNext())
                    {              
                        EmailFunction.sendEmail(ExchangeIP, port, sendersInputIterate.next(), toAddress, subject1.next(), content, uploadedFiles);  
                        resultMessage = "The B-mail has been sent successfully :";



                        Thread.sleep(sleeptime);
                    }
                        Thread.sleep(iterationInterval);

                }

            }catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                ex.printStackTrace();               
                resultMessage = "There were an error: " + ex.getMessage();
                } finally 
                {

                        request.setAttribute("Message", resultMessage);             
                        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp").forward(request, response);
                }                   
        }
```

Comment: Did you try to use Map?

Comment: no..i have used arraylist to create sender ids

Comment: `Map<String, Number>` - key - emailID; value - counter

Comment: can you please tell me in detail about using the map.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment

> can you please tell me in detail about using the map.

Map interface is covered by oracle here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Here's a very basic example of the use of a map to count based on String value. Note that this exmaple assumes that emails are case sensitive (which I believe the are supposed to be, but the majority of implementations would assume they weren't, I'll leave it as an exercise to you to work out how to make them case insensitive)

```
public class EmailCounter {

    private Map<String, Integer> destinationEmailCount = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        EmailCounter emailCounter = new EmailCounter();
        emailCounter.addToMailCount("email1@mail.com");
        emailCounter.addToMailCount("email1@mail.com");
        emailCounter.addToMailCount("email1@mail.com");
        emailCounter.addToMailCount("email2@mail.com");

        System.out.println("email1@email.com was mailed " + emailCounter.getEmailCount("email1@mail.com") + " times");
        System.out.println("email2@email.com was mailed " + emailCounter.getEmailCount("email2@mail.com") + " times");
        System.out.println("email2@email.com was mailed " + emailCounter.getEmailCount("email3@mail.com") + " times");
    }

    public void addToMailCount(final String emailAddress) {
        Integer existingCount = destinationEmailCount.get(emailAddress);
        if (existingCount != null) {
            destinationEmailCount.put(emailAddress, Integer.valueOf(existingCount.intValue() + 1));
            return;
        }
        destinationEmailCount.put(emailAddress, Integer.valueOf(1));
    }

    public int getEmailCount(final String emailAddress) {
        Integer count = destinationEmailCount.get(emailAddress);
        return count == null ? 0 : count.intValue();
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
email1@email.com was mailed 3 times
email2@email.com was mailed 1 times
email2@email.com was mailed 0 times
```

Comment: You're using an unsuitable collection. A List is simply a collection of values, an ArrayList uses an array to store those values. A Map on the other hand uses the concept of key-value pairs. The example above shows you how you can use the email address as a key, and the count as a value.